# Yii - CHttpRequesterror while functional unittesting in module

Tags: php, module, yii

When I'm trying to execute a functional unittest of a module within my Yii code, I keep receiving the following error:

```
CException: CHttpRequest is unable to determine the request URI.
```

At first, I though it was because it couldn't find the module. However, If I change the url to a wrong one, I get a correct error,s tating it couldn't find the view.

This is how my testing code looks like

```
public function testViewControllerModule()
{
    ob_start();
    Yii::app()->runController('module/controller/view');
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you haven't set any server variables, i.e `$_SERVER` and you might be doing something like this in your controller:

```
Yii::app()->request ....
```

So before you run your test, make sure you use a fixture for the [server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) also. I think this should suffice for now:

```
$_SERVER=array(
    'REQUEST_URI'=>'index.php', // the other fields should follow
);
```

However to run functional tests i would recommend using SeleniumRC, you won't have to do these workarounds then, and can simulate user clicks also, i think.

Read the initial [guide to Functional Testing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional) , read the [selenium rc phpunit guide](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html), and also the [CWebTestCase documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebTestCase).

Notes: You might still have to use fixtures for some variables, and i don't have much experience in testing(which is bad), so i'm not very sure if i am completely correct about selenium.

Comment: let me know how this works out, i would be interested to help you further.

Comment: was i completely off course with the answer? do let me know, that way i could either delete this answer, or improve it. some feedback is better than no feedback..

Comment: Woeps sorry, I completly lost track of this post... Will try this answer out tonight :-), thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

bool.devs answer works so far.

This blog post explains the origin of the exception pretty well: 
http://mattmccormick.ca/2012/09/14/unit-testing-url-routes-in-yii-framework/

In my case, I generalized the solution and have set the following variables in /www/protected/tests/bootstrap.php:

```
...

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = 'index-test.php';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =  '/index-test.php';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'index-test.php';

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

Consider using **'index-test.php' instead of 'index.php'** because it contains the config 'test.php' which is responsible for fixtures and maybe other test relevated configurations.


If someone has better suggestions feel free to comment :)

Kind regards